14 CFR Part 101 -- Moored Balloons, Kites
I am hoping someone can hep me interpret the Regulations regarding moored balloons. I want to fly a 5-1/2 ft lighted helium balloon at night at 500 feet AGL.
I have made exhaustive searches online, contacted and gotten a response from the FAA by email, and spoke with the FSDO responsible for my area, but I still don't feel like I have a resolution.

I feel like since the balloon is less than 6' and none of the other title 14 101 Subpart A 101.1 Applicability criteria apply, then my balloon is not subject to any regulations in Part 101.

The FSDO kept telling me all they can do is refer me to the regulations, they couldn't talk openly about my situation.


I got the impression the FDSO didn't know, I asked if a 8" helium balloon required an automatic rapid deflation device and they also said "all I can do is refer you to the regulations".

Because your balloon is less that 6' diameter, you are correct in presuming the subpart 101.1 you are asking about does not apply. However, other parts may, and the FSDO isn't going to research this for you or give you blanket permission...

You can also try law.se for how to interpret this specific section of the law, and know the possible jurisprudence, there are also Part 101 comments. Local regulations may apply (e.g. Dallas) and may add constraints not in Part 101.
